# How to deal with DateTime and TimeZone in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, datetime, timezone, azure

I am working on Silverlight Application with SQL Azure. As I know if `DateTime` Kind is Unspecified, Silverlight will change it to `Local` and it will save to Azure as UTC time.

Everything working as expect but when I get `DateTime` data from SQL Azure, its Kind is `Unspecified` and Silverlight does not convert back to `Local` time when its display on UI.

For example: I use my application in Rome (UTC +1), I set date to 15:00 then save to database. In database it will save as 14:00 (UTC).

Now I open page to edit that data, it query from database as 14:00 with `Unspecified` kind and it also show 14:00 in page, which obviously incorrect.

I tried to set `DateTime` kind at DomainService (before return those data to client) by checking if its kind is unspecified, set it to UTC. This time when I change DateTime on my page its kind is always UTC.

It seems like silverlight will convert date only if its kind is `Unspecified`, otherwise it do nothing, it also can't convert `DateTime` from database to display properly even those `DateTime` has Kind.

I want to know, are there any solutions or work around for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know its stored in UTC, have you tried setting datetime, then using having Silverlight explicitly convert to local time? I am not familiar with Silverlight, but in other forms of .NET, you have to do this conversion explicitly for  UI operations.

```
DateTime dt = GetDateFromDB();

dt = dt.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.UTC);

DateTime dtAsLocal = dt.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: I tried to do this and it will show on UI correctly but when I change datetime in UI and save into database, it won't convert from Local to UTC. For example, if I set datetime in Rome (UTC +1) to 15:00:00, it save into database as 15:00:00 instead of 14:00:00

Comment: can you share the code you are using to do the prep for save?

Comment: I know about my problem, someone do not use Binding but set datePicker.SelectedDate value directly to DateTime, in this case there is no DateTimeKind.

Comment: Isn't `SpecifyKind` a static method?